# I dont want normalize.css in Pure CSS framework. I guess normalize.css included in base module. How can I do it?

Tags: pure-css

I am a beginner to Pure CSS framework. As per my requirement, I don't want to include normalize css in it. I guess normalize is available in one of the Pure CSS module (base).  How can I do it?

Comment: just curious. Why don't you want to use 'normalize css'? What don't you like about using it? I ask because it used quite often and it is interesting to hear your reasons to not use it.

Comment: As It overrides some of the element on the webpage(pages which we do not serve) to get cross browser consistency. I don't want it to override. Here, http://purecss.io/customize/ I achieved it.  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?pure/0.6.0/grids-min.css&pure/0.6.0/forms-min.css">

Comment: How can I install pure grid-only with bower. I guess $ bower install pure --save will install full featured pure in my project.